# Why does my ReactJS app do a full refresh after refreshing a file in the public folder?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-pdf

I am writing my web app using React. My app downloads a PDF in the public folder, and then it renders the pdf using the `react-pdf` library. The problem is that, once the pdf is downloaded to the `public` folder, the webpage refreshes completely. Since the app does a full refresh once I modify some part of the code, I expect that the refresh happens because I save a new file in the project. How do I avoid the full refresh for items updated in a folder different from `src`?

Comment: "once the pdf is downloaded to the public folder" sounds strange. Why would your frontend app download something to its public folder? That can't happen in a regular server scenario...

Comment: This is because `react-pdf`, in order to render the pdf, needs a url, but my file is saved locally. So, the only way I found to render it was to put it in the public folder and call it with `http://localhost:3000` (where the development server is hosted) + file location in the pdf folder. Is there another way to do this? I couldn't find any.

Comment: See here: https://react-pdf.org/advanced#on-the-fly-rendering

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Have you found any solutions to this?